# Array typing issue in build macro

Tags: macros, haxe

Note: My issue [#4417](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4417) was closed, but I didn't want to be that guy who opens another issue for the same thing.

Based on [#3132](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/3132), `[ { "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 2 } ]` doesn't compile unless you specifically type it to `Array<Dynamic>` or whatever type encompasses both. That's fine I guess, but inside of the build macro below, there is nowhere for me to type the array, and I get an error.

In general, I can make map literal notation work using `untyped` (http://try.haxe.org/#3dBf5), but I can't do that here since my types haven't been constructed yet.

```
macro public static function test():Array<Field> {

    var fields = Context.getBuildFields();

    // parse the JSON
    var o = Context.parseInlineString('{ "arr": [ { "a": 1, "b": 2 }, { "a": 2 } ] }', Context.currentPos());

    // ["test" => json] map literal notation
    var a = [{ expr : EBinop(OpArrow, macro $v { "test" }, o), pos : Context.currentPos() }];

    // creates: "public var json:StringMap<Dynamic> = ['test' => json];"
    var nf:Field = {
        name : "json",
        doc : "docs",
        meta : [],
        access : [APublic],
        kind : FVar(macro : haxe.ds.StringMap<Dynamic>, { expr : EArrayDecl(a), pos : Context.currentPos() } ),
        pos : Context.currentPos()
    };

    fields.push(nf);

    return fields;
    // error: Arrays of mixed types... 
}
```

Without knowing ahead of time what the structure of the json is, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `untyped`, by constructing an intermediate `EUntyped(o)` expression (more simply `macro untyped $o`).

Alternatively, you can traverse the parsed object and add `ECheckType` to `Dynamic` expressions to every array, generating something like to `([...]:Array<Dynamic>)`.

The implementation of this would look something like calling the following `checkTypeArrays` function with your parsed `o` object, before building the  map literal expression.

```
static function checkTypeArrays(e:Expr):Expr
{
    return switch (e) {
    case { expr : EArrayDecl(vs), pos : pos }:
        macro ($a{vs.map(checkTypeArrays)}:Array<Dynamic>);
    case _:
        haxe.macro.ExprTools.map(e, checkTypeArrays);
    }
}
```

An improvement to this would be to only wrap in `(:Array<Dynamic>)` the arrays that fail `Context.typeof(expr)`.

Comment: This looks complicated and confusing enough to be a correct solution wrt macros. Thanks! I'll try it out later.

Comment: Found some time, and the first solution worked perfectly! I guess it's literally the same as adding untyped in the try.haxe link I posted.

Comment: @MSGhero I recommend you try the second solution as well, since with it you could keep the generated `json` contents more strictly typed (than simply `Dynamic`).